# Store inbox sms to avoid repeat url hit

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new in android studio. I'm developing an app which hit a url with incoming sms and its work properly here is working code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            try {
                if (bundle != null) {
                    final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                        String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                        toast.show();
                        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                        String cDate = df1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        String cTime = df2.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        String ime = tm.getDeviceId();
                        useGet(ime, cDate, cTime, "0", senderNum, message);
                    }
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
            }
```

But I want to hold inbox sms or it's index which already hit url for avoid repeat hit in case of if sms not hit url and user hit back manually by button click.

Answer (score 0):

save these details in local db and verify whetehr it is already done or not before hitting the url

Comment: is there any method to store in app? I dont want to use any db.

Comment: yes you can use Shared Preference (But you can store only few values).